# <xsl:for-each multiple filters (on child elements of current selection)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am adding an additional condition to an existing xsl stylesheet.

The simplified XML input content is the following:

```
<form id="MY_CONTENT">
<variable id="processInfo">
    <variable id="teacher">
        <variable id="taxId" value="12345"/>
        <variable id="name" value="Nancy"/>
    </variable>
    <variable id="student">
        <variable id="taxId" value="12345"/>
        <variable id="name" value="Nancy"/>
    </variable>
    <variable id="student">
        <variable id="taxId" value="23456"/>
        <variable id="name" value="Will"/>
        <variable id="tutoringtInformation">
            <variable id="specialNeeds">
                <variable id="description" value="Special Need"/>
            </variable>
        </variable>
    </variable>
    <variable id="student">
        <variable id="taxId" value="98765"/>
        <variable id="name" value="Dustin"/>
        <variable id="tutoringtInformation">
            <variable id="preferences">
                <variable id="reason" value="Mornings"/>
            </variable>
        </variable>
    </variable>
    <variable id="student">
        <variable id="taxId" value="784512"/>
        <variable id="name" value="Steve"/>
        <variable id="tutoringtInformation">
            <variable id="available" value="false"/>
        </variable>
    </variable>
</variable>
```

Right now the xslt is only filtering out elements of type "student" whose taxId is different from the taxId on the "teacher" element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:for-each select="/form/variable[@id = 'processInfo']/variable[@id = 'student' and variable[@id = 'taxId']/@value != ../variable[@id = 'policyHolder']/variable[@id = 'taxId']/@value]">
                <xsl:variable name="taxId" select="variable[@id = 'taxId']/@value"/>

                <resultSet>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/form/variable[@id = 'processInfo']/variable[@id = 'student' and variable[@id = 'taxId']/@value = $taxId]"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/form/variable[@id = 'processInfo']/variable[@id != 'student']"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/form/variable[@id != 'processInfo']"/>
                </resultSet>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Along with that condition I also want to filter out **student** elements that **do not** have any of the following (an or condition):

- a child element **tutoringtInformation** which has a child element **specialNeeds**
- a child element **tutoringtInformation** which has a child element **preferences**

In the provided XML input it should output both Will and Dustin. How can I achieve that behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your verbal description "a child element tutoringtInformation which has a child element specialNeeds" translates into the XPath `tutoringtInformation/specialNeeds`, only you don't have any child elements named according to the data type they represent but only `variable` elements with an `id` attribute naming that type so you rather want `variable[@id = 'tutoringtInformation']/variable[@id = 'specialNeeds']`. If you put that into a predicate (i.e. in square brackets `variable[@id = 'student'][variable[@id = 'tutoringtInformation']/variable[@id = 'specialNeeds']]`) you check for the existence. As you do not want your element to have those type of children/grandchildren use the negation with `not()`: `variable[@id = 'student'][not(variable[@id = 'tutoringtInformation']/variable[@id = 'specialNeeds'])]`. You can add the second condition with `and` or a further predicate.

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me in the right direction by chaining the **specialNeeds** and the **preferences** in the same predicate using **or** and chaining with the previous filter.